# Emacs command to convert JS Object to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, object, emacs

Is there an emacs library or command to convert JS Object to JSON?

Something such as `{a:"b", c:1}` to `{"a":"b", "c":1}` with a command `M-x wrap-to-json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer seems to be "no".  I've done some (shallow) research, and the only Emacs packages which handle JSON are json.el (part of the standard distribution as of 23.1), and [json-mode](https://github.com/joshwnj/json-mode), which is available with package.el.  The former deals with serialization of JSON to and from elisp data structures, and the latter is a major mode for editing JSON.

Source: [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/JSON)

Answer (score 2):

here's a quick function to convert a given region by piping through node

```lisp
(defun js->json ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command-on-region (region-beginning)
                           (region-end)
                           "node -e 'console.log(JSON.stringify(eval(require(\"fs\").readFileSync(0, \"utf-8\"))))'"
                           (current-buffer)
                           t))
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried @directed laugh's answer, but it gave me this error (on Emacs 27.1):

> undefined:1 {a: 1, b: 2}
> ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
> at [eval]:1:47
> at Script.runInThisContext (node:vm:129:12)
> at Object.runInThisContext (node:vm:307:38)
> at node:internal/process/execution:79:19
> at [eval]-wrapper:6:22
> at evalScript (node:internal/process/execution:78:60)
> at node:internal/main/eval_string:28:3
>
> Node.js v18.13.0

I changed the function to pass the region as an argument to `JSON.stringify()` and it worked:

Here's the function that worked for me:

```elisp
(defun json-stringify-region ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command-on-region
   (region-beginning) (region-end)
   (format "node -e 'console.log(JSON.stringify(%s))'"
           (buffer-substring (region-beginning) (region-end)))
   (current-buffer) t))
```

What it does is to use the Emacs built-in function `shell-command-on-region` to execute the `node` command that is formatted to use the marked region as an argument to `JSON.stringify()`.

(I didn't have enough reputation to comment the answer, and there were too many pending edits).